# Getting 'TypeError: a is not a function' associated to redux.js with reactnative test

Tags: javascript, react-native, react-redux

Hello I am testing a reactnative api and I am getting getting 'TypeError: a is not a function'  and found it here in the redux.js file.

```
return funcs.reduce(function (a, b) {
    return function () {
      return a(b.apply(void 0, arguments));
    };
  });
}
```

I am so lost on what this could be. I tried to look at the call stack and see what called the compose function that returns this funcs.reduce but it does not show anything.

This is the full error
  ● Test suite failed to run

```
TypeError: a is not a function



  at node_modules/redux/lib/redux.js:406:14
  at node_modules/redux/lib/redux.js:433:47
  at createStore (node_modules/redux/lib/redux.js:51:33)
  at Object.<anonymous> (src/js/store.js:68:222)
  at Object.<anonymous> (src/js/shared/tracking/events.js:8:14)
```

Comment: Maybe you are trying to create a reducer from something that is not a function.

Comment: going through with dev and seeing if we can find the issue. He mentioned it may be a reducer issue too.

Comment: Post the code of how you combine your reducers, the reducer function and how you create your store if it is available.

Comment: Got it I was mocking function incorrect

Comment: Could you say a bit more about what you did wrong?

Comment: @AlexG in an api request .js file we have a function that updates the credentials in the store. I was doing updateCredentials = jest.fn(); and should have been doing updateCredentials = store => next => action => jest.fn()